# Does this Confucius quote about time of achievement make sense in the modern world?

Tags: confucius

Confucius said:

> It does not matter how slowly you go so long as you do not stop.

I have doubts about it.  You may manage in slow ancient China, but in our rapid world, which so quickly developing, where people need to do their business quickly, there are lot of competitors...
And from interpersonal relation point of view: some people just may not bother to wait for you.

Comment: Don't isolate the quote from it's context.

Comment: @CriglCragl what is the context then?

Comment: Grabbing some words of a philosopher from 2.5k years ago, with little connection to Western exegesis until the last century will not get you far. It would be like reading some lines of Plato & smugly saying 'I don't even live in a cave though - loser!' If you are interested in Confucious, read the Analects, they are very interesting. When asking questions here, *do the leg work*. The pithier the quote the more likely there are translation issues. +In 1st page of results, it seems it' s a misattribution of:  "as long as you keep at it, you can make a needle by wearing down an iron rod" - Li Bai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 譬如为山，未成一篑，止，吾止也！譬如平地，虽覆一篑，进，吾往也！

I searched for this sentence, and it seems that this is the [original Chinese sentence](https://www.translatorscafe.com/tcterms/en-US/question.aspx?id=123235). It is kind of hard to translate, and the sentence you quoted had been distorted somehow. I first search for its modern Chinese translation and then use the google translation:

> For example, mounding soil to build a mountain can be completed with only a basket of soil, but I stop doing it. This is my own stop! Take another example! Although I have only dumped a basket of soil, if I can continue to move forward, I will have a day of success in the accumulation of time, so I will continue to move forward, it is my own decision!

Now you can see this is incredibly distorted. The original meaning is about perseverance. There is nothing to do with the philosophy. Actually, I don't know why this sentence is so popular among western countries with such an untenable reference.